# C# API - Upload File with json

Tags: c#, swagger, .net-6.0

As documented here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/ I would like to do same behavior in my C# controller API with also a working swagger docs.

I found a way to read file and Json object with:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
{
    var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var file = form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
    var jsonString = form["json"].ToString();
...
```

But with this solution I'm not able to generate the swagger docs correctly (try it out section).

Do you have any suggestions?

Auto-generated swagger:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Example
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      summary: Uploads data
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

expected swagger docs:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Example
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /upload:
    post:
      summary: Uploads data
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                id:
                  type: string
                  format: uuid
                address:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    street:
                      type: string
                    city:
                      type: string
                profileImage:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

Using this code:

```
public class Document
{
    public string CompanyId { get; set; }
    public DocumentType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, [FromForm] Document model)
{
...
```

With Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 6.5.0 it generate:
[image: swagger.html]

Comment: `I'm not able to generate the swagger docs correctly` is not a problem description we can help with. **Edit the specific error or problem into your question.**

Comment: Hey @IanKemp, let me know if now is more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put the IFormFile and the other fields as parameters:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, [FromForm] string id, ....)
{
    ....
}
```

You can also bind a complex object:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, [FromForm] MyModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I have latest installed:
``` 
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
```
Using your code, with this version I don't have MyModel as json object

Comment: @SergioDallaValle `MyModel` was just an example to show you can bind any class.

Comment: Yes I updated my question with what you suggested and how changed my swagger page. If you see, the swagger generator convert the Object model to single props

Comment: That's the expected behavior. If you don't like it you can always put a `[FromForm] string json` and pass a json string.

Comment: This works but I need the preloaded json schema as `[FromBody]` decorator provide.

Comment: I don't think you can have both `multipart/form-data` and a body.

Comment: It's possible, you can check with https://editor.swagger.io/ the swagger doc:  https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/